# BLAT Does Not Accept my %BODY% argument

Tags: batch-file, blat

Trying to understand how to send the BODY variable correctly?

I receive the following from using BLAT in my batch file:

```
SET BODY="exit error code from NET USE = %ERRORLEVEL%. Please contact the Business Systems Technical Team On Call Person"
```

Here's the use of BLAT:

```
"C:\Program Files\BLAT\blat.exe" -To myemail@domain.org -Subject "RAD File Transfer Error" -Body %BODY%
```

> Blat v3.2.19 (build : Nov 18 2017 03:15:08) 64-bit Windows, Full, Unicode
>
> Blat saw and processed these options, and found fault with the last
>   one...
>
> -To myemail@domain.org
>      -Subject RAD File Transfer Error
>      -Body Not enough arguments supplied for option: -Body Blat found fault with: -body
>
> -body     : message body, surround with quotes (") to include spaces

Here's where the SET BODY is:

```
copy /Y "C:\channels\filetransfer_process\*" "D:\MSCMRADbackups1\"
echo %ERRORLEVEL% 
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 (   
    echo Setting BODY1 at: %date% %time%
    SET BODY="exit error code from Backup of RAD file = %ERRORLEVEL%."
    goto :mailerror
    )
 ) ELSE (
 EXIT
 )
```

Comment: Please post more of your code. It might be due to using a code block (`if` or `for`), for example. You should also try prepending `echo` to the `blat.exe` call and see if the variable is expanded correctly.

Comment: Are your `set` and `blat` command lines placed within a loop or any other parenthesised block of code?

Comment: BTW: You dont need to use external tool to send mails from windows command line: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7779b3bb-dfcc-4ab3-966d-9c71d5369ad7/send-email-using-vbscript

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but maybe the answer might help someone. Since your string contains spaces, you have to use quotes when passing it to blat as an option.

So use **-Body "%BODY%"** instead of -Body %BODY%.

Answer (score 0):

Another belated answer here, but posting it anyway in the hope it will help someone.

The -Body option expects one -- and only one -- argument.  The fact that you get the following error:
"-Body Not enough arguments supplied for option: " means that you did not supply an option, which means that %BODY% was null when you passed it to Blat.

You're depending upon BODY being set within nested IF statements.  I'd suggest you try using the following line before the outer IF block:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

After you've SET BODY, access the delayed expansion value by using bangs (exclamation marks) instead of percent signs.  So, in your blat command, use:

```
blat ... -Body !BODY!
```

(Quotation marks not needed here if they were supplied in the SET command.)

Look for help on SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION (and ENDLOCAL, which is not always necessary) elsewhere.  Much has already been written about it.